# how to send attachment via form in combination with ajax jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a contactform with 1 attachment possibility. 
The data is sent correctly via php file. But in combination with AJAX echo , it does not work anymore.
What i am doing wrong?

The form:

```
<form class="contact-form-php" action="" method="post" name="contactform" id="contactform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input class="nex-bcf" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Uw Naam" required />
    <input class="nex-bcf" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Emailadres" required />
    <input class="nex-bcf" type="text" name="telefoon" placeholder="Telefoon" />

    <textarea name="message" class="nex-bcf" placeholder="Schrijf Bericht" required></textarea>
                        <br />
    <span style="color: #484848;">Send attachment(s)</span>
                        <br /><br />
    <input class="nex-bcf" type="file"  id="attachment1" name="attachment1" placeholder="Bijlage1" />
    <input class="nex-bc nex-cc nex-bgch" name="contactform" id="contactform_send" type="submit" value="Versturen" />
</form>
```

My javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
    $('#contactform_send').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#contactform_send').val($(this).val());
    var data;

    data = new FormData();
    data.append( 'file', $( '#attachment1' )[0].files[0] );
     $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'helpers/email_send.php',
        data : data,
        success :  function(data) {                   
                    $(".email_wrapper").delay(500).fadeIn(500).show(function()
                    {
                        $(".email_wrapper").html(data);

                    });

        },
        complete :  function(){
           $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: $('#contactanchor').offset().top -100},
           'slow');

        }

    });

  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<form class="contact-form-php" method="post" name="contactform" id="contactform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input class="nex-bcf" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Uw Naam" required />
    <input class="nex-bcf" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Emailadres" required />
    <input class="nex-bcf" type="text" name="telefoon" placeholder="Telefoon" />

    <textarea name="message" class="nex-bcf" placeholder="Schrijf Bericht" required></textarea>
                        <br />
    <span style="color: #484848;">Send attachment(s)</span>
                        <br /><br />
    <input class="nex-bcf" type="file" id="attachment1" name="attachment1" placeholder="Bijlage1" />
    <button class="nex-bc nex-cc nex-bgch" name="contactform" id="contactform_send">Versturen</button>
</form>
```

I'll show you what I do with my own AJAX upload form. A few things about your form struck me as being problematic. I don't think it's a good idea to keep the `action=""` included in the `<form>` tag, when you're uploading with AJAX. This attribute should be omitted entirely. I also replaced the `<input type="submit" />` of your form with a `<button>`, because in my experience using an input with `type="submit"` can interfere with the AJAX.

Now, in the JavaScript. The **`FormData()`** constructor should be given the HTML element of the form, as a parameter. I passed in `$("form")[0]`. In your code, where you've used `$("#attachment1")[0].files[0]`, I notice I use something different. I replaced this with what I use, `.prop("files")[0]`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contactform_send').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#contactform_send').val($(this).val());
        var data;

        // FormData() must be constructed with the form element on the page
        data = new FormData($("form")[0]);
        data.append("file", $("#attachment1").prop("files")[0]);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "helpers/email_send.php",
            data: data,
            dataType: "text",
            // these next two are just what I use on mine, remove if it doesn't work for you
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response) {                   
                $(".email_wrapper").delay(500).fadeIn(500).show(function()
                {
                    $(".email_wrapper").html(response);

                });
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('#contactanchor').offset().top -100},
                'slow');
            }

        });

    });
});
```

Something else to take note of: You use the variable `data` to store the `FormData()` object, but you also use a variable named `data` as the parameter to the `success` function. This is very likely to cause errors, and I'm positive it would affect the AJAX in some way. Fortunately, the parameter name for your `success` function is arbitrary. I changed it to `response`.

Comment: I agree. This works fine. But one thing: i can not see my php echo anymore after submit...

Comment: Make sure your `function (response)` under `success`, has the line in the middle `$(".email_wrapper").html(response);` I wouldn't know why it would work before, when `function (data)` had the same name as your variable. Maybe try it again the other way.